# when building a fullstack project with express, how do I use "res.status(200).json( {some information...} )" in the front end?

Tags: node.js, express, authorization, response

I am learning about express servers, but I do not understand why all the tutorials I am watching are writing code like the following 3 lines when dealing with responses

```
res.status(200).json({user});

res.status(401).json("Wrong username");

res.status(500).json(err);
```

How does this help my home.html (or home.ejs) file??

for example, if I am building a login feature like:

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {

    const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json("Wrong credentials!");
    }
   
    const hashedPassword = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(user.password, process.env.PASS_SEC);
    const originalPassword = hashedPassword.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    if (req.body.password !== originalPassword) {
      return res.status(401).json("Wrong credientials!");
    }
  
    const accessToken = jwt.sign(
      {id: user._id, isAdmin: user.isAdmin},
      process.env.JWT_SEC,
      {expiresIn: "3d"}
    );
    const { password, ...others } = user._doc;
    res.status(200).json({...others, accessToken});

  } catch (err) {

    res.status(500).json(err);

  }
});
```

How does those "res.status" lines actually let me do things on the front end. Like how do I access this information, e.g. to save the accessToken in a request header for my next request, or how do I manipulate the html file to say `hi ${user.username}` or something like that.

Or if an error occures, how do I make my application say "username is wrong" or "login failed" or whatever, because res.status() is NOT doing any of that let me tell you...

99% of the content I find online uses react or angular, I only use plain JS and HTML, any help is appricated because I have no clue where to look and I have enough with learing express and do not want to learn react

Answer (score 0):

In an express server you can return responses in an intuitive way like below:

```
return res.status(200).send({
    'message' : 'Okay'
});
```

The status codes explain the status of the request. Though we have freedom to use any status code that we want the general practice is that the we follow:

1. 2xx - Okay (request successful)
2. 4xx - An issue with the client end of the request - you can use this to throw out errors when something is wrong with the client whos sending the request , like the user credentials is wrong or the requested record does not exists etc.
3. 5xx - An issue with the server like the db connection failed, or file write failed etc.

On the front end depending on the status code of the request you can change the UI. Also note that the message that you send via res.send({}) is also available in the front end which u can use to show the user of the front end.